# Unidentified iPhone Vibration Alert

Tags: iphone, vibrate

When I have my iPhone 4s on vibrate only mode (side switch down), sometimes I a single vib alert from an unidentified app.  None of my apps have applicationIconBadgeNumber set, so, what the heck is making it vibrate?

Comment: It happened again just now.

Comment: I *used* to get similar vibrations when the phone lost and regained carrier signal, but I haven't seen (or should I say heard/felt) it since 5.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in Settings > Notifications for an app that only shows "Sounds". If you have more than one app, turn on Badges or Banners (temporarily) until you get the next notification. The app with the new badge should be the culprit.

Otherwise, go through the list one by one and disallow Sounds for each app successively until you find the offending app.

Comment: So none of them have ONLY sounds...they either have sounds and something else, or they are completely disabled.

Comment: @AJC Then you may have to go with the second option and turn Sounds off one by one until you find the app.